# UITableView with in a scrollview not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, horizontalscrollview

I'm a newbie for ios sdk.I've created a sample app.In that app I'm using a `tableview` and on clicking any cell in the table view i'm pushing a `ScrollViewViewController`( scrollView with pageControl ) on it.In `ScrollViewViewController` I'm loading the views which will have each a `tabBarController`.
In the `tabBar` there are 5 `tabBarItems`.And on second `tabBarItem` corresponds to a `viewContoller` which has a `tableView` as subview.
Here the problem is that on the second `tabBarItem` `tableView` is scrolling fine in the fist page of the `scrollView`.But once i swipe to the next page in `scrollview` and on that page if i select the second `tabBarItem` which loads a `tableView` and that `tableView` is not scrolling.
Please help me.
I've been struck here from more than a month
:(
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer but so far it seems that a tableview and scrollview actually use the same Delegate. Because of this they can fire each others methods and mess stuff up. Not sure if that helps explain it better. Still searching for a work around.

Answer (score 3):

This approach isn't really recommended.

The problem being that UITableView inherits from UIScrollView.

It's actually written in the UIWebView documentation:

> "Important: **You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects**. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

[image]